# Would a question on how to approach self-defense when intoxicated be viable?

Tags: discussion

I wrote most of the question before finding myself not certain of whether it was actually a good fit for the site. I think it's a viable question overall as to how one should best defend when your reflexes and coordination are a bit off. What leaves me a bit iffy is that I'm having trouble finding a way of expressing it that isn't "what's the best way?" (opinion) or "has this been covered in martial arts?" (lists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is fine. Here is one attempt at wording:

> How should I modify my self-defense strategy if I know I am impaired?

Comment: [Done](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/10502/how-should-i-modify-my-self-defense-strategy-if-i-know-i-am-impaired)